# Pycharm using incomplete stubs when doing autocomplete/type-checking

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm trying to annotate a variable holding the return of a call to `asyncio.start_server`. The problem is, Pycharm is not able to identify all the methods that the `AbstractServer` class contains.

Basic example:

```
import asyncio as a

async def server():
    svr: a.AbstractServer = await a.start_server(lambda r, w: None, "127.0.0.1", 5555)
    await svr.serve_forever()
```

This code works (when I use a real callback and connect a client). Pycharm complains though and shows a "weak error" on the `await svr.serve_forever()` line:

> Unresolved attribute reference 'serve_forever' for class 'AbstractServer'

Which is weird because `AbstractServer` in `events.py` definitely contains that method:

```
class AbstractServer:
    """Abstract server returned by create_server()."""

    . . .

    async def serve_forever(self):
        """Start accepting connections until the coroutine is cancelled.

        The server is closed when the coroutine is cancelled.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

    . . .
```

In Pycharm though, when I click the little `*` in the border next to `class AbstractServer` to see the stub, this is what it redirects me to (in `events.pyi`):

```
class AbstractServer:
    sockets: Optional[List[socket]]
    def close(self) -> None: ...
    @coroutine
    def wait_closed(self) -> Generator[Any, None, None]: ...
```

For some reason, the stub only lists two methods and a property for `AbstractServer`. So even though the class does have methods like `serve_forever`, Pycharm seems to only be referencing the incomplete stub.

Does anyone know why Pycharm's stub for this class is incomplete and how it can be fixed? I'd rather not need to add in ignore-comments just to circumvent the type-checker. I tried "Invalidate Caches/Restart", but that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the repercussions of this will be, but here's my "fix" in the meantime:

- I navigated to `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\typeshed\stdlib\3`, which is where the stubs are located
- I renamed `/3/asyncio` to `asyncio_BACKUP` (essentially deleting it from Pycharm's perspective without actually deleting it). I could have also just renamed the specific `events.pyi` file inside `3/asyncio/` and left the rest alone.
- I restarted IntelliJ (actually I ran "Invalidate Caches/Restart", although I'm not sure if that was necessary)

It's auto-completing fine now. Pycharm seems to have fallen-back to using the `events.py` instead of using the incomplete `events.pyi` stub.

I hope someone posts a proper fix. This seems to be fine in the meantime though. Maybe I'll try just reinstalling Pycharm; although that seems like a heavy fix.

---

---

## Warning

This solution ended up being poor. Pycharm seems to be unable to load <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> documentation for anything without an associated `.pyi` entry. Now when I try to load documentation, it loads the documentation for `asyncio` itself. I'm going to rename the folder back to what it was, and selectively re-name `events.pyi` instead to limit the problems this causes.